# Ajax Tab error Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: value

Tags: ajax, dynamic, tabs

I am trying to create ajax tabs dynamically and storing their ID's in a session. I am getting an error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value". I am able to create the first tab by invoking the click button event. When I click the button and invoke the same event on the second try...I get the error. Seems like I am referencing a tab ID or container\tab that is no longer defined or contained in session?

I have researched this thoroughly and can't seem to find the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have the correct scriptmanager and assembly references on my asp page. Here is the asp code and the code behind snippet.

```
                    <div>
                    <asp:Button ID ="AddTab" Text="Add Tab" OnClick = "addTab_Click" runat="server"/>
                    <AjaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainerContent" runat="server"  Height="150px" BackColor="White"  AutoPostBack="True" 
                    OnActiveTabChanged="TabContainerContent_OnActiveTabChanged" >
                    </AjaxToolkit:TabContainer>
                    <asp:Label ID="currentTabIndex" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
                    </div>
                    </td>
```

Code Behind

```
 private List<string> dynamicTabIDs;

        protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["dynamicTabIDs"] != null)
        {

            dynamicTabIDs = (List<string>)Session["dynamicTabIDs"];

            foreach (string tabID in dynamicTabIDs)
            {

                AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tab = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                tab.ID = tabID;
                tab.HeaderText = "Tab " + (TabContainerContent.Tabs.Count + 1).ToString();
                Label tabContent = new Label();
                tabContent.ID = "lbl_tab_" + TabContainerContent.Tabs.Count.ToString();
                tabContent.Text = "Tab " + (TabContainerContent.Tabs.Count + 1).ToString();
                tab.Controls.Add(tabContent);

                TabContainerContent.Tabs.Add(tab);
            }


        }//end if
        else
        {

            dynamicTabIDs = new List<string>(); 
        }

    }


     protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {  

     Session["dynamicTabIDs"] = dynamicTabIDs;  

        }

     protected void TabContainerContent_OnActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

         currentTabIndex.Text = TabContainerContent.ActiveTab.ID; 

     }


    public void addTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tab = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
        tab.ID = "tab" + Convert.ToString(TabContainerContent.Tabs.Count);
        tab.HeaderText = "Tab " + (TabContainerContent.Tabs.Count + 1).ToString();
        Label tabContent = new Label();
        tabContent.ID = "lbl_tab_" + TabContainerContent.Tabs.Count.ToString();
        tabContent.Text = "Tab " + (TabContainerContent.Tabs.Count + 1).ToString();
        tab.Controls.Add(tabContent);

        TabContainerContent.Tabs.Add(tab);

        TabContainerContent.ActiveTab = tab;

        dynamicTabIDs.Add(tab.ID); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach to accomplsih this. I created static tabs and just set them to visible true/false depending if they are used or not. I couldn't get dynamic tabs to work. I did have to restrict the number of customer numbers to 15 orders with this approach.

I found that it was very easy to bind data to a gridview within Ajax tabs. Of course you needed you script manager ajax reference declared in the asp page and ajax reference update to web.config file. You also need to add the ajax css style to an existing style sheet. i tried using a seperate one and it didn't work.

ASP HTML

```
<AjaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
                            Visible="false" ScrollBars="Both"
                            CssClass="Tab2" Width="1326px" Height="464px" >

<AjaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Empty" Enabled="true"    ScrollBars="Both" CssClass="Tab2">

<ContentTemplate>
<div style="overflow:auto;width:1287px; height: 418px;">
 <font color="white" size="1" face="Verdana">

 <asp:GridView ID="SalesOrderView1"     runat="server" BackColor="White"   BorderColor="#DEDFDE"visible="False"BorderStyle="None"      BorderWidth="1px" 
 CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" 
 GridLines="Vertical"     HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <AlternatingRowStyle      BackColor="White" />
 <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE"    ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
 <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
 <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
 </asp:GridView>
  </div>
  </font>
 </ContentTemplate>
   </AjaxToolkit:TabPanel>
      <AjaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="Empty" ScrollBars="Both" CssClass="Tab2">
 <ContentTemplate >
 </AjaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

C# Code to bind data to the gridview on click button event.

```
                        SalesOrderView1.Visible = true;
                        TabPanel1.Visible = true;
                        TabPanel1.HeaderText = Order_List[multi_order_count];
```